# How can i send messages from android to my laptop python program?

Tags: networking, python-3.5

I am trying to send messages from python 3.5 program running on android to the python program running on my laptop.
I searched Google so many times but nothing had me .
So anyone can help to go in the right direction .
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by messages you means you want to communicate between the two programs and not the SMS messages.

If this is the case, make sure that both the systems are on the same network, it may be the local network or the internet. Then you can very easily send messages from one program to another by using the IP Address of the second program.

Comment: Thanks Mr. kishu for answering .They are of same network . So can you tell me how i can send messages using ip addresses

Comment: Basically you would have to set one program as a server and the other as a client. Server would be listening for connections and client would initiate the connection. After the connection is established, then you can send the messages,

Comment: have a look at this [example](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/socket-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unspecific. But in general you can do something like this with sockets.

[Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html)